# Any strategies for measuring dwell time inside an app?

Tags: lightning-web-components, analytics

We have a number of pages and each page contains several questions (input fields). If a user just "checks all the boxes" without pausing to think between each one the quality of their input is open to question.

So I'm wondering if there is a good way to track and record [dwell time](https://theevergreenagency.co.uk/knowledgebase/what-is-dwell-time-and-how-do-you-measure-it/) per input in an LWC e.g.:

- Leverage field change history on the back-end?
- Custom SObject and additional front-end code?
- ???

Comment: I've not used this but [Lightning Interaction Event Type](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_eventlogfile_lightninginteraction.htm) could be an avenue

Comment: Thanks @cropredy. The documentation doesn't build confidence but will certainly take a look at that - don't know it existed.